# GO: How to share code between multiple apps in the same repository

Tags: go, module, shared-libraries

I'm new to Golang. I have multiple apps residing in the same folder in a mono repository.

```
apps
   app1
      go.mod
      go.sum
      main.go
   app2
      go.mod
      go.sum
      main.go
   app3
      go.mod
      go.sum
      main.go
```

There is also a `go.work` file in root directory that wraps these apps in a `use` block. The apps are AWS Lambda functions that are deployed independently.

How can I create a shared library that can be used by each app? I have some code that should be made reusable or else I'll end up copy-pasting everything. I've tried adding a `shared.go` file under `apps` with no luck.

Comment: Follow the tutorial [How To Write Go Code](https://go.dev/doc/code): Create a module at the root repository.  Remove the other go.mod files and go.work.   A section of the tutorial describes how to import a local module.  https://go.dev/doc/code#ImportingLocal

Comment: The tutorial mentions the following: `A module is a collection of related Go packages that are released together`. I need to release each app separately. Is it possible to build and package them individually if they are part of the same module?

Comment: Modules are the unit for version control, not for building or deployment.  If you plan to version the applications and shared library as one unit, then it's simpler to put everything in single module. Packages are the unit for building. You can build multiple applications out of a single module.  If you do plan to version the applications and shared library independently of each other, then it's simpler to create multiple repos with a go.mod at the root of each repo.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I'll accept your answer if you post one.